# "Can't get attribute" when Pickling Object

Tags: python, pickle

My save code is written as so in a file called 'MachLearn.py':

Whilst looking for this code I find out I accidentally overwrote it with an old version :/. It was essentially structured like this:

```
class attibuteGenerator():
   def __init__(self):
   #more class stuff

   def returnAttributes(self, rating, position):
       #func stuff

if __name__ = "__main__":
    ag = attributeGenerator():
    with open('attributeGenerator_pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(f, ag)
```

My open code is written as so in a file called "mainGame.py"

```
def main():
    with open('attributeGenerator_pickle', 'rb') as f:
        bob = pickle.load(f)
        print(bob.returnAttributes(34, "LW"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is there an issue with my code? It's giving:
[image]

Comment: Please include the **full** error message so we can have more information about the error, like which line caused it.

Comment: Added it, sorry

Comment: In order to unpickle a class instance, a definition of the class (`attributeGenerator` in this case) must be found with the same name, in the same module as before. Looks like you no longer have that definition present.

Comment: I'm not understanding, do I have to put the code for the class definition within mainGame.py?

Comment: Don't provide pictures of code or errors. **Always** provide them as formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error arises when you attempt to unpickle an object, such as a class instance, and you don't have access to the relevant class in your current Python session. You should reimport the packages you were using to generate the objects that you pickled.

The following minimal script will reproduce this problem:

```
import pickle

class my_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2

inst = my_class()
with open('file.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(inst, f); f.close()

del my_class # Deletes the class and causes the problem

with open('file.dat', 'rb') as f:
    new_inst = pickle.load(f); f.close()
```

with error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-6571eae10a31> in <module>
     12 
     13 with open('file.dat', 'rb') as f:
---> 14     new_inst = pickle.load(f); f.close()

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'my_class' on <module '__main__'>
```

This can be resolved by removing the line: `del my_class`.